# How to set JSON NSData with ASIFormDataReuest

Tags: iphone, wcf, web-services, json, asiformdatarequest

Hi I want to pass my userName and Password to WCF Webservice from iPhone. I'm using ASIFormDataRequest.

**Here is my code**

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setPostValue:txtUsername forKey:@"userName"];
    [request setPostValue:txtPassword forKey:@"password"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json; charset=utf-8"]; 
    [request startAsynchronous];
```

How do I pass JSON Data?
I could use this...
[request appendPostBody:jsonData]; // JSON as NSData

but how do I set JSON to NSData?

**NSData *jsonData = @"{'userName':'john', 'password':'secret'}";**

Please help me!

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: sorry I update the question, I want to set JSON to NSData!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you want to encode the JSON in UTF-8 as stated in your header:

```
NSString *json = @"{'userName':'john', 'password':'secret'}";
NSData *jsonData = [json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request appendPostBody:jsonData];
```